# iOS6 mapkit span

Tags: mapkit, zooming, html, ios6, ios6-maps

The new maps provided with iOS6 do not allow a span lower than about .001. 
Has anyone else seen this issue?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude= 37.980600, .longitude= -87.593932};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta= 0.0, .longitudeDelta =  0.0}; //smaller the number = greater zoom
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Even using 0.0 as the zoom span, I can open the map in the simulator and zoom further with a gesture.
Also worth noting is that I can zoom further in the actual 'Maps' App using gestures, than I can in my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works exactly as you describe, and I sent off some sample code to Apple to see if they had anything to say about it. No answer yet. It must be intentional, pe